# Why do presidents receive a pension after their term of office?

Tags: president, public-sector-compensation

When the president ends their term of office in several countries, they receive a pension for life. Why is this? (One guess I have is that it could possibly be to secure their future so their presidential decisions are not affected by eventual future financial troubles.)

What were the problems when the president didn't receive a pension?

Comment: Not exactly on point, but France has the practice of including all living former Presidents, *ex officio*, in the Council of State (basically, the highest body overseeing public law and administrative law with both cabinet meet discussion/policy setting features, and quasi-judicial features).

Comment: @ohwilleke doesn't France also give an automatic pension to ministers?  [Schwartzenberg](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9on_Schwartzenberg) lasted one week as Health Minister, after stating he was pro-legalization for cannabis in 1988 and I believe his pension was upheld.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I don't know one way or the other.

Comment: @italian Based minister

Comment: I want to write an answer that says "In some countries, it's normal that any salaried job comes with an occupational pension", but I have a nagging feeling that what OP is really asking about are features of post-presidential payment that differ from a normal occupational pension...?

Answer (score 45):

At least in the US, where a presidential pension was only instituted in 1958, it was seen as embarrassing for a former president to be struggling financially. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_S._Truman#Post-presidency_(1953%E2%80%931972)):

> Upon leaving the presidency [in 1953], [Harry S.] Truman ... taught occasional courses at universities, including Yale, where he was a Chubb Fellow visiting lecturer in 1958. In 1962, Truman was a visiting lecturer at Canisius College. As a former president, Truman decided that he did not wish to be on any corporate payroll, believing that taking advantage of such financial opportunities would diminish the integrity of the nation's highest office. He also turned down numerous offers for commercial endorsements.
>
> Once Truman left the White House, his only income was his old army pension: $112.56 per month (equivalent to $1,089 in 2020). Former members of Congress and the federal courts received a federal retirement package; President Truman himself ensured that former servants of the executive branch of government received similar support. In 1953, however, there was no such benefit package for former presidents, and he received no pension for his Senate service.
>
> ...
>
> In 1958, Congress passed the Former Presidents Act, offering a $25,000 yearly pension to each former president, and it is likely that Truman's claim to be in difficult financial straits played a role in the law's enactment.

---

The current presidential salary is $400,000 (but, it's complicated) and the  pension is $219,000 annually (ibid.), as well as many other benefits like office space, treatment at military hospitals, and Secret Service protection.

Comment: To add on to this: if you believe, as Truman did, that profiting from being a former president diminished the integrity of the office, then a presidential pension makes it easier and encourages former presidents to resist those enticements.

Comment: Yeah, in Chile happened the same thing with president Patricio Aylwin. After his term ended in 1994, he suffered financial straits and presidential pension was instituted. It looked embarrassing too.

Comment: Considering how many millionaires there are in Congress, I suppose many of them would struggle financially at $25k/year...

Comment: @gerrit $25k/year in 1958, using the comparision for the army pension in the quote, I would guess that corresponds to approximately $250k/year in 2020 (harsh, but survivable ;-)

Comment: @quarague That depends on whether the pension is  adjusted for inflation…

Comment: @gerrit The law doesn't specify an amount, it says "Each former President shall be entitled for the remainder of his life to receive from the United States a monetary allowance at a rate per annum, payable monthly by the Secretary of the Treasury, which is equal to the annual rate of basic pay, **as in effect from time to time, of the head of an executive department**" (bold mine) https://www.archives.gov/about/laws/former-presidents.html EX1 right now is $219,200 https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/pay-leave/salaries-wages/salary-tables/pdf/2021/EX.pdf reduced to $203,500 on pay freeze

Comment: According to usinflationcalculator.com, $25,000 in 1958 is equivalent to $240,439.45 in 2021.  So @quarague's guess is pretty close.

Comment: @dan04 the precise figure depends on the month.  You can use the Bureau of Labor Statistics' official calculator at https://data.bls.gov/cgi-bin/cpicalc.pl; using November for both years (because it's the latest month for which data are available in 2021) [gives $239,610.34](https://data.bls.gov/cgi-bin/cpicalc.pl?cost1=25000&year1=195811&year2=202111)

Comment: @phoog You're quibbing over a 0.3% difference lol. I think it's a bit extreme to give inflation numbers down to the cent. An approximate value of $240,000 is probably about how much precision there actually is here ...

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I'm not quibbling at all; I'm pointing out the official source and noting that it's more precise.  The precision is superfluous, but I'm sure that at least someone out there prefers to use the official source.

Answer (score 18):

The details depend on the country, of course.

In Germany, a former president receives not just a pension (called honorary / honor pay), but also some staff, offices, etc. for what are called "remaining tasks" from the office. Basically, the former president is *expected* to act in a manner consistent with the dignity of the office and the interests of the nation. They tend to be older, with the presidency coming at the end of a long career, which makes them more of elder statesmen than active politicians.

In the United States, Jimmy Carter was one of the more active [ex-presidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-presidency_of_Jimmy_Carter#Diplomacy) in recent times. He got involved with North Korea and the Middle East as a credible spokesperson not *directly* connected to the then-current administration. This allowed him to visit places and say things an active government member might not have said.

Comment: What do Jimmy Carter's activities have anything to do with the president's pension?

Comment: They show that he remained an asset for the following governments, and thus rated a *salary* rather than a *pension*. Except that calling it a salary would have made him less effective.

Comment: I think he does not have an official title but the "EX-President" when involved with affairs in those countries, so officially he couldn't receive a "salary" or be compensated by the US government.

Comment: @r13, for exactly that reason it was a good idea to give him a pension. And other presidents before and after acted in similar roles.

Comment: Universities in the U.S. have similar practice with a professor transitioning to "emeritus" status and no longer having mandatory teaching, research, or administrative duties, but continuing to have an office and access to university facilities with limited departmental staff support, sometimes teaching a single class or small seminar or lecture series, and often doing part-time research and publishing a reduced volume of papers.

Comment: Jimmy Carter may have been the most active former president, but most former presidents continue to make themselves available for consultation by the current president.

Comment: @ohwilleke: A similar _Emeritus_ status exists also in Germany as well as many other European countries. My guess is that this is based on the idea that science is, in the original sense of the word, a vocation for life.

Comment: do remember that what Carter did was outside the control of and certainly not endorsed by the US government on many occasions. He merely used his status as a former president to push for political agendas he personally liked.

Comment: @Schmuddi Humanities professors and others can be emeritus too.

Comment: @ohwilleke, the old German *emeritus* system for professors was a loss of the *requirement* to hold classes at age 68, while retaining all the full *rights* of being a professor. At 78 they lost some administrative rights, but still retained academic rights. For instance, an *emeritus* could still grade exams. This was abolished a generation ago, but all those who were already professors at the time of change got "grandfathered." So a *president emeritus* and a *professor emeritus* would be different things -- a *president emeritus* cannot sign treaties.

Comment: @jwenting, on many occasions what he did was tacitly endorsed by the government, giving the then-current government "plausible deniability."

Answer (score 9):

Speaking generally, one reason which would make this a
beneficial feature of a political system could be to make it less important for the president to be afraid about destitution after their term; and thus make them less susceptible to corruption.

For example, after her 12-year period in office, Angela Merkel will receive 65% of her compensation until the end of her life, which is the maximum amount possible for someone in her role. In her case that's roughly 15.000€ monthly. This means that at no point during her active time as chancellor was she ever forced to care much about what she'd be doing after her mandate was over, and presuming good character, there was little monetary, objective reason for her to bow to any less-than-decent offers during the time when even small decisions would possibly have made huge amounts for some company or other party. Or to jockey for some other position within some company or the political system after their prestigious position is over...

Answer (score 3):

The United Kingdom  only instituted an ex-Prime Minister's allowance in 1991 and it is still limited to 50% of salary.  There has been a lot of unfavorable press directed at a couple of recent PMs (Tony Blair & David Cameron) and their post-office "business consultancies"  where they are clearly aiming for large-scale personal profit.

At least one columnist in the [New Statesman](https://www.newstatesman.com/politics/uk-politics/2021/04/we-should-be-more-generous-our-former-prime-ministers-and-yes-includes-david) feels that a larger pension & continued govt support might have prevented at least some of this and given the opportunity for them to remain statesmen with a higher purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons, but they boil down to a few most relevant categories

1. Respect - Attaining the most prestigious job on the planet arguably should
   automatically come with financial security.
2. Image - Imagine the scenario of a former president having to sell personal
   possessions to keep bill collectors at bay, or being for-closed on.
3. Security - Keeps him/her less tempted to write some book divulging secrets or from
   having to work for a shady arms dealer who does business in the Middle East.
4. Employment options limited - Most come from senatorial or other elected positions
   that they can't return to.
5. Tradition - This was decided when being President did not
   automatically guarantee millions in speaking deals

Comment: For [United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States) presidents only (***"the*** *most prestigious job on the planet"* and *"being President did automatically guarantee millions in speaking deals"*)? Can you make it clear in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).